Resize the QdialogButtonBox when the entire QGIS window is resized (Qt Designer)
I am creating a QGIS plugin with Qt Designer and want the QDialogButtonBox (the box containing the OK and Cancel buttons) to resize when the main window is resized. In the default QGIS dialogs (see last image), the QDialogButtonBox resizes automatically with the window. How can I achieve this? I tried adding a vertical or horizontal layout and adjusting its properties, but it didn't work. I also tried to create a vertical layout first and then add the QdialogButtonBox on it but no success afterwards.


Typical resized window


While this is not really a GIS-related question, I will attempt to put a QGIS spin on this answer.
If you are building a plugin, you will likely start with a dialog with buttons bottom as seen here opened in Qt Designer:

First, right-click on the dialog and select Layout->Layout vertically.

Now you can insert additional layouts e.g. a Grid Layout:

Let's drag a couple of custom QGIS widgets (a QgsMapLayerComboBox and a QgsFieldComboBox) into the grid layout and label them with QLabels.

By default, the grid layout is spaced evenly, but ideally we want to stretch the combo boxes. To do this, click on one of the combo boxes, expand size policy under the Property Editor and change the horizontal stretch to 1.

Ok, that looks better. You could also add a vertical spacer between the button box and the grid layout.

Finally, you may find it useful to inspect some existing QGIS widgets. You can find all the QGIS .ui files on GitHub here:
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/5481dabd3214b79100984493551625dbd6597aec/src/ui
You can download the raw .ui files and open them in Qt Designer to see exactly how the widgets which make up the QGIS application are structured. For example, here is qgsmapsavedialog.ui open in Qt Designer:


It works like a charm!
